# iText 7 How do I display the data in a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

Below is the code I've used to fetch the required data from database, I've checked it using breakpoints and **userName** do contains the data.

`var userName = db.M_User.Where(x => x.UserID == userId).Select(x => x.Full_name).FirstOrDefault();`

I try to display it using the below code

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("I, "+userName)
```

The **I** is printed, except the **userName**

I already have the form in views and these codes are for print the pdf only

Comment: If the `userName` happens to consist of non-Latin letters, you may have to use a font that can encode them.

Comment: @mkl the `userName` do not have any non-Latin letters, it only contains a name like 'Steven' and that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the destination and somehow it works

```
string dest = "C:\\test\\"+userName+".pdf";
```